# Limit a user's function/action

Tags: php

Hello my scenario is that on a specific date my user would be able to update data but only limit their update to only 3 times. Here is my code so far.

```
if(date('m','d' == '04','01')){
     $sql="update tbl_enroll fields,fields,fields where student_id='".$_POST['student_id'] . "'";
     $pow = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
}
```

Any idea on how to limit his **update** ? Is there something i need to change in my db structure? would appreciate any help.

Comment: Fixed your quotes to please the syntax hilighter. And restored a missing concatenation `.`

Comment: If you would thumbs down at least explain why.

Comment: I wasn't aloud to fix it due to 6 char min limit, so mean! :D

Comment: Please correct your code. That would produce a syntax error in PHP. And please read on SQL Injections. http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Comment: @rationalboss already read about sql injection. thanks for the concern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add 'counter' to tbl_enroll. Something like this:

```
ALTER tbl_enroll ADD COLUMN counter SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL;
```

Then, your code should be something like this:

```
// check how many times has this user edited:
$sql = 'SELECT counter FROM tbl_enroll WHERE student_id=123';
$pow = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_eror());
$pow = mysql_fetch_assoc($pow);

$allowed = true;
if ($pow['counter'] >= 3) $allowed = false;

if (date('m') == '04' && date('d') == '01' && $allowed) { // allow edit only on april 1
    $sql = "UPDATE tbl_enroll SET something='something',other_field='',counter=(counter+1) WHERE student_id=123"; // this is just an example, please focus on "counter=(counter+1)"
    $pow = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: else if (!$allowed) echo "something something" +1 for taking the time to write the complete and correct code.

Comment: You can avoid the additional select, just put counter <= :updateLimit at the end of the where clause and catch the query with a mysql_affected_rows to see if anything was updated

Answer (score 4):

Add a count column to your table and increment each time the user updates. If the count is 3 disallow the operation and show an error message.

Comment: By _iterate_ we assume you mean _increment_.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski language fail. :)

Answer (score 3):

Add a count column to the table as @TigOldBitties suggested and add at the end of the WHERE clause `AND updateCount <= 3`

--
Are you sure the `if(date('m','d' == '04','01')){` is correct? I think it should be `if(date('m','d') == '04','01'){`

--
And even `if(date('m','d') == '04','01'){` can't be right, what is it you're trying to do here?

Comment: still wrong. date('m','d'). D is a string and a long integer is expected there. What you can do is: if (date("'m','d'") == "'04','01'") {}

Comment: My idea is when the system time would be on a specific date and update button would pop out and let the user update only 3 times and if the 3 times is up it would not show.